# Java switch-case with Enum variables "Constant expression required" error

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, constants

I have this enum:

```java
public enum Pebble {
    RAGE(NamedTextColor.DARK_RED, "Rage Wave", "Channel Rage"),
    FLEET(NamedTextColor.AQUA, "Dash", "Speed Surge"),
    CHARISMA(NamedTextColor.GREEN, "Charisma Aura", "Silver Tongue"),
    STEALTH(NamedTextColor.DARK_PURPLE, "Flashbang", "Smoke Bomb"),
    MOLTEN(NamedTextColor.GOLD, "Fireball", "Flame Touch"),
    STEEL(NamedTextColor.DARK_GRAY, "Iron Skin", "Steel Buddy"),
    ROLL(NamedTextColor.YELLOW, "", "");

    public final NamedTextColor color;
    public final String primary;
    public final String secondary;

    Pebble(@NotNull NamedTextColor color, @NotNull String primary, @NotNull String secondary) {
        this.color = color;
        this.primary = primary;
        this.secondary = secondary;
    }
}
```

And I need to use the primary and secondary strings to get different outputs using this switch-case statement:

```java
switch(abilityName) {
    case Pebble.RAGE.primary -> {...}
    case Pebble.RAGE.secondary -> {...}
    ...
}
```

But because these values are not initialized as constants at compile time, I get an error.

I saw a post that suggested adding something like this to the enum:

```java
public static Pebble byName(String abilityName) {
    for (Pebble value : values()) {
        if(value.primary.equals(abilityName) || value.secondary.equals(abilityName)) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then for the switch-case you can just do this:

```java
Pebble pebble = Pebble.byName(abilityName);
switch (pebble) {
    case RAGE -> {...}
    case FLEET -> {...}
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't work for me since I need 2 different outputs per Pebble.

No matter how I rack my brain I can't figure out a neat solution to this, any suggestions?

Comment: you could add an if statment  to check if its primary or secondary inside the switch case

Comment: or you could create an enum named Skills and add alll the skills there and the Pebble enum will house the Skills then you could use a switch with the Skills enum

Comment: *"But this doesn't work for me since I need 2 different outputs per Pebble."* - I don't understand this.  Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Anon I made a second enum and it works.

Comment: @StephenC If you want me to edit it at least explain what you need me to clarify, I feel like I couldn't have put it in any simpler way than I did.

Comment: What do you mean by two outputs?  Outputs to what?  Where are you outputting things?  That's what I mean.  Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to design the object.

Here is an alternative.

> *"... I saw a post that suggested adding something like this to the enum ...*
> *... But this doesn't work for me since I need 2 different outputs per Pebble. ..."*

Then, create two methods, one to return the *Pebble* given separate evaluations.

```java
static Pebble primary(String abilityName) {
    for (Pebble pebble : values()) {
        if (pebble.primary.equals(abilityName)) return pebble;
    }
    return null;
}

static Pebble secondary(String abilityName) {
    for (Pebble pebble : values()) {
        if (pebble.secondary.equals(abilityName)) return pebble;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then, just check which *Pebble* it is, first.

```java
Pebble pebble;
if ((pebble = Pebble.primary(abilityName)) != null) {
    switch (pebble) {
        case RAGE -> { }
        case FLEET -> { }
        case CHARISMA -> { }
        case STEALTH -> { }
        case MOLTEN -> { }
        case STEEL -> { }
        case ROLL -> { }
    }
} else if ((pebble = Pebble.secondary(abilityName)) != null) {
    switch (pebble) {
        case RAGE -> { }
        case FLEET -> { }
        case CHARISMA -> { }
        case STEALTH -> { }
        case MOLTEN -> { }
        case STEEL -> { }
        case ROLL -> { }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does seem like it would have worked, but I ended up taking the suggestion of another user and making a second enum to hold the abilities instead.